# How to show a query statement where it ends with a certain letter?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have this problem in my query statement in which I have to exclude all the salesperson whose first names ends on y (Lily, Maddy), and cannot use the keyword 'LIKE'.

Here is my query and output so far, this is what it should look like even after adding the exclusion of the names that end in the letter y:

Expected output but without the exclusion:

[image]

When adding commands such as "REGEXP_LIKE":

[image]

**TL;DR** I need to find a way to exclude all names that end with the letter y in my table without getting rid of the, in Emp Name and without using the keyword "LIKE"

Comment: How is this question different from the question you asked yesterday, which already has a Correct Answer you selected?

Comment: Yesterdays was regarding on how to show letters that should only show names that starts with letter B and has to include the letter l. In this case I was just having trouble showing the comma when using regexp_life or substr while trying to exclude the letter y in first names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't post any sample data, I made some on my own.

```
SQL> with
  2  employees (employee_id, first_name, last_name) as
  3    (select 1, 'Freya', 'Gomez'  from dual union all
  4     select 2, null   , null     from dual union all
  5     select 9, 'Lily' , 'Marlen' from dual
  6    ),
  7  orders (salesman_id, order_id) as
  8    (select 2, 100 from dual union all
  9     select 9, 900 from dual
 10    )
 11  select e.employee_id,
 12         e.first_name ||', '|| e.last_name full_name,
 13         o.order_id
 14  from employees e left join orders o on o.salesman_id = e.employee_id
 15  order by e.employee_id;

EMPLOYEE_ID FULL_NAME       ORDER_ID
----------- ------------- ----------
          1 Freya, Gomez
          2 ,                    100
          9 Lily, Marlen         900   --> you want to get rid of this row
                                       --  because Lily ends with a "y"
SQL>
```

If you add a `WHERE` clause (line #15), you'll get *wrong* result because - as you said - you want to keep the *comma* row:

```
<snip>
 11  select e.employee_id,
 12         e.first_name ||', '|| e.last_name full_name,
 13         o.order_id
 14  from employees e left join orders o on o.salesman_id = e.employee_id
 15  where substr(e.first_name, -1) <> 'y'
 16  order by e.employee_id;

EMPLOYEE_ID FULL_NAME       ORDER_ID
----------- ------------- ----------
          1 Freya, Gomez

SQL>
```

`NVL` comes to rescue! See line #15:

```
<snip>
 11  select e.employee_id,
 12         e.first_name ||', '|| e.last_name full_name,
 13         o.order_id
 14  from employees e left join orders o on o.salesman_id = e.employee_id
 15  where nvl(substr(e.first_name, -1), ',') <> 'y'                         --> this
 16  order by e.employee_id;

EMPLOYEE_ID FULL_NAME       ORDER_ID
----------- ------------- ----------
          1 Freya, Gomez
          2 ,                    100

SQL>
```

Comment: Oh now it makes sense on how missing the NVL results in the statement not displaying the comma. Thank you again, you're a lifesaver

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid everyone who's first name ends in Y, then use this:

```
    where substr(first_name, -1) <> 'y'
```

Comment: this also gets rid of the "," thats supposed to be showing in emp name

Comment: Please clarify your question. You are concatenating the last_name to comma_space to first_name. You are adding the comma. All you need to do is add a where clause to your query. It will still return a comma, but only show people who's first name does not end in a Y. And why the LEFT join to employees? Are you expecting some to not be found?

Comment: I apologize for being unclear. The expected output for the first two rows should be:
Emp Name                  Total Sale      
------------------------- ----------------
,                           $18,245,463.50
Gomez, Freya                 $8,081,332.30

Adding the where clause would return 
Emp Name                  Total Sale      
------------------------- ----------------
Gomez, Freya                 $8,081,332.30
Freeman, Florence            $4,341,842.14

Comment: Sorry just to add on to this, the reason for the join is that employees does not display the , but the employee id does but I still needed to show the employee names as well as the comma.